# how do i create a true "multiple lines" column in a picture library sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, picture-library

I would like to have a pic lib and would like to have the normal multiple line of text like tin list etc..
Any ideas why there is such a limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
1) Site Actions -> Site columns -> Create -> Create Multiple lines of text (Rich or Enhanced rich) -> Ok.
2) Go to your Picture library -> Picture and Library settings -> In content types area click on Picture content type -> Add from existings site or list columns -> Select and add your multiline column -> Ok.

Comment: The second way: open your field in SharePoint Manager http://spm.codeplex.com/ and set RichText propery in true for your miltiline field

Comment: BioGeneZ when i try to create a site colum there is no Multiple lines of text (Rich or Enhanced rich) listed.
I'm on SP 2010

Comment: I get to add a new site column and add anew content type but still have the limitations of 255 characters.
Any ideas?